# Cats, Dogs and Bears - how are they related?

Tags: evolution, zoology, mammals, phylogenetics, speciation

What is the ancestral relationship between **cats**, **dogs** and **bears**?

I presume they are more closely related to one another than other [paraphyletic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraphyly) clades of mammal.

- Which came first?
- What did their common ancestors look like?
- What are their geographical origins?

Comment: You'll like this: http://tolweb.org/tree/

Comment: and this: http://www.onezoom.org/mammals.htm

Comment: Clades are, by definition, monophyletic.

Answer (score 6):

Cats, dogs and bears all belong to the [Carnivora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnivora) clade of mammals, but they are not the only ones belonging to this clade.
For instance, cats are more closely related to mongoose and hyenas than to dogs or bears, who in turn are more closely related to raccoons, weasels, and walruses.

Their common ancestors likely displayed various adaptations to a carnivorous diet, as the name of the clade suggests, and which are still present in many extant Carnivora (the panda being a well-known exception).

Together with many other groups of mammals, Carnivora are part of a clade named [Laurasiatheria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurasiatheria) thus named because they may have originated in the [Laurasia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurasia) supercontinent, which comprises nowadays north America and Eurasia.